# Shortest paths in the Hypercube

Tags: combinatorics, geodesic, discrete-geometry

We'll ask for lengths of shortest paths in the hypercube which obey dimensional constraints.

Given $n\in\mathbb N$, the *hypercube* or *n-cube* is the $n$-fold product of the unit interval (so it's *not* the Hilbert cube!). It is thus the set
$$F_{n,n}\:=\:\left\{\sum\nolimits^n_{i=1}\beta_ie_i\:\Big\vert\:
\beta_i\in \big[0\,,1\big]\right\}$$
where $\,(e_i)_{1\le i\le n}\,$ denotes the standard ONB of $\mathbb R^n$, equipped with the Euclidean distance. For $1\leqslant d\leqslant n\,$ the union of $\,d$-dimensional faces of the $n$-cube is defined as
$$F_{n,d}:=\left\{\sum\nolimits^n_{i=1}\beta_ie_i\:\Big\vert
\text{ where $d$ coefficients }\beta_i\in \big[0\,,1\big],\text{ the remaining ones live in }\{0,1\}\right\},\\[2.5ex]
\text{then } F_{n,1}\:\subsetneq\:F_{n,2}\:\subsetneq\:\ldots\:\subsetneq\: \,F_{n,n}\,.$$

> What is the length $\,s(n,d)\,$ of a shortest path between the corner at the origin and the opposite corner at $\,(1,1,\ldots,1)\,$ when the path is constrained to lie in $F_{n,d}\,$?

For $\,F_{n,1}$, thus edges only, and $\,F_{n,n}$, allowing for the straight line, the question is quickly answered by $\,s(n,1)=n\,$ and $\,s(n,n)=\sqrt n\,$:
\begin{matrix}{\begin{matrix}&d\\n&\end{matrix}}&1&2&3&4&\ldots\\
1&1\\
2&2&\sqrt 2\\
3&3&\sqrt 5&\sqrt 3\\
4&4&?&??&2\\
\vdots&&&&&\ddots\end{matrix}

The less obvious entry $\,s(3,2)=\sqrt 5\,$ is furnished by 
[this eye-catching answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2251367/316749)
to the post "What is the geodesic between two opposite corners of a cube on its surface? [closed]". But what about all the rest?

How can the decreasing (certainly!) sequence
$$\,s(n,1),\;s(n,2),\;\ldots,\;s(n,n-1),\;s(n,n)$$
be determined? I didn't find references, neither @SE  nor in the residual internet. Furthermore I'm not sure about the appropriate tagging of the post, but omitting [graph-theory](/questions/tagged/graph-theory) was intended.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a generalization of the "visual proof" referred to in the question.

If $p_i\geq0$ $(1\leq i\leq d)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^d p_i=n$ then $$\ell({\bf p}):=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^d p_i^2}$$ is minimal when all $p_i$ are equal. When the $p_i$ are forced to be integers then we should make them as equal as possible. To this end assume
$$n= q d+r, \qquad q\geq1,\quad 0\leq r<d$$
and put
$$p_i:=\left\{\eqalign{&q+1\qquad(1\leq i\leq r)\cr &q\quad\qquad(r+1\leq i\leq d)\ .\cr}\right.$$
I claim that
$$s_{n,d}=\ell({\bf p})=\sqrt{dq^2+r(2q+1)}\ .$$
I shall only prove that $s_{n,d}\leq\ell({\bf p})$. Nevertheless I can't see how one could do better.

In the ${\bf y}$-space ${\mathbb R}^d$ we consider a virtual box $$V:=[0,p_1]\times[0,p_2]\times\cdots\times[0,p_d]\subset{\mathbb R}^d\ .$$ This box is built up from  $d$-dimensional unit cubes, called *chambers*. The main diagonal $\sigma$ of this box connects ${\bf 0}$ with ${\bf p}=(p_1,\ldots ,p_d)$ and has length $\ell({\bf p})$. This diagonal passes a certain number of chambers in turn. We now interpret these chambers as $d$-dimensional faces of the original cube $C:=[0,1]^n\subset{\mathbb R}^n$, so that $\sigma$ can be viewed as an unfolding of an admissible path from ${\bf 0}$ to ${\bf 1}$ in $C$.

The intended "backfolding" of $\sigma$ is accomplished as follows: Assign each interval $[k-1,k]$ $(1\leq k\leq p_1)$ on the $y_1$-axis the number $k$, then assign each such interval on the $y_2$-axis one of the  next $p_2$ numbers, and so on along the other $y_i$-axes, until all numbers from $1$ to $n$ have so been distributed. We now identify each interval $0\leq x_k\leq 1$ on one of the axes of ${\mathbb R}^n$ with the corresponding $y_i$-interval on the proper axis of ${\mathbb R}^d$.

By projection onto the $y_i$-axes each piece $\Delta \sigma\subset \sigma$ lying in some chamber gets therewith  assigned $d$ different numbers from $[n]$, and these numbers indicate which coordinates $x_k$ shall be "active" along $\Delta \sigma$, in other words: on which $d$-dimensional face of $C$ the "backfolded" piece  $\Delta \sigma$ shall lie. It follows that $\sigma$ "backfolds" isometrically to an admissible path of length $\ell({\bf p})$ in $[0,1]^n$.

Comment: This approach is best possible, because your "backfolding" process can be inverted into an "unfolding" process. When a coordinate of the witnessing path of $s_{n,d}$ becomes 1, it changes the active face. This coordinate is exchanged for another coordinate that starts with 0. So it is wandering from chamber to chamber, which are the cubes in the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^d$. As exactly $n$ coordinates become 1 in total, we get a path from $(0,...,0)$ to some $(p_1,...,p_d)$ with $\sum p_i=n$ of same length. The shortest such path is the one you describe.